# Magento2: How to change location product tab

Tags: magento2

I want to change location button product tab:

[image]

I enable on the template hints and found such a file. I'm not sure if I should edit places in this file?

I would like the tab "oferty" to be displayed first.

details.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$_config  = $this->helper('Sm\Market\Helper\Data');
$tabStyle = $_config->getProductDetail('tab_style');

$show_custom_tab   = $_config->getProductDetail('show_custom_tab');
$custom_tab_name   = $_config->getProductDetail('custom_tab_name');
$customtab_content = $_config->getProductDetail('customtab_content');
?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')): ?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items <?php echo $tabStyle . '-style' ?>" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php if ($tabStyle == "default" || $tabStyle == "vertical") { ?>
                <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                        <?php
                        $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                        if (!trim($html)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                        $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                        ?>
                        <li class="data item title"
                            aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            $alias ?>-title"
                            data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $alias ?>">
                            <a class="data switch"
                               tabindex="-1"
                               data-toggle="switch"
                               href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               $alias ?>"
                               id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                               $alias ?>-title">
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                $label ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_custom_tab) { ?>
                        <li id="tab-label-customtab" class="data item title" aria-labeledby="tab-label-customtab-title" data-role="collapsible" role="tab" data-collapsible="true" aria-controls="product.info.customtab" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
                                <a class="data switch"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   data-toggle="switch"
                                   href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                   $alias ?>"
                                   id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                   $alias ?>-title">
                                    <?php echo $custom_tab_name ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>

                <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                        <?php
                        $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                        if (!trim($html)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                        $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                        ?>

                        <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            $html ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php if ($show_custom_tab) { ?>
                        <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="customtab" data-role="content">
                                <?php
                                echo $customtab_content;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                    <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                    ?>
                    <h2 class="data item title resp-accordion"
                        aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $alias ?>-title"
                        data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    $alias ?>">
                        <a class="data switch"
                           tabindex="-1"
                           data-toggle="switch"
                           href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>"
                           id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>-title">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            $label ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>

                    <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    $alias ?>" data-role="content">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $html ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php if ($show_custom_tab) { ?>
                    <h2 id="tab-label-customtab" class="data item title resp-accordion" aria-labeledby="tab-label-customtab-title" data-role="collapsible" role="tab" data-collapsible="true" aria-controls="product.info.customtab" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
                        <a class="data switch"
                           tabindex="-1"
                           data-toggle="switch"
                           href="#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>"
                           id="tab-label-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           $alias ?>-title">
                            <?php echo $custom_tab_name ?>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="data item content resp-tab-content" id="customtab" data-role="content">
                        <?php
                        echo $customtab_content;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>


        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For example you can see below from Magento v2.2.4 by default in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:99`, but is for example, because I saw you code and you used a theme and the theme used many modules and I saw your printscreen which display a custom **tab**.

You can search in your theme or in your third-party modules, this `group="` from XML files and you can find it.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Or you can see in `Sm\Market\Helper\Data` from `getProductDetail` method what is it in method and you can find it.